# Check table values when loading html page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have recently started to use jQuery and I would like a little help, on a function that I would like to implement, in practice I have a html table in which for each row there is the course, professor, day, hour, status and a button to cancel my reservation, I initially created a small function in which when I click the button it changes the value of STATUS from ACTIVE to CANCEL and then through a post sends data to the server.

This is my code - I'm using a jsp page and I fill the columns using jstl

```js
$(document).on('click', '.table-remove', function(e){
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    $(this).prop("disabled",true);
    var col1=row.find('td:eq(0)').text();
    var col2=row.find('td:eq(1)').text();
    var col3=row.find('td:eq(2)').text();
    var col4=row.find('td:eq(3)').text();
    var col5=row.find('td:eq(4)').text();
    var sessionValue= $("#hdnSession").data('value');
        $.post("Serverlet_prenotazioni_disdette",{corso:col1,professore:col2,giorno:col3,ora:col4,stato:col5,user:sessionValue},     
            function(data){
               row.find('td:eq(4)').html('Disdetta');
               alert(data);
            });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-md table-hover text-center"   id="table">
            <tr style="background-color:#17a2b8;color:white">
                <th class="text-center">Utente</th>
                <th class="text-center">Corso</th>
                <th class="text-center">Professore</th>
                <th class="text-center">Giorno</th>
                <th class="text-center">Ora</th>
                <th class="text-center">Stato</th>
                <th class="text-center"> </th>        
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <c:forEach var = "rip" items = "${prenotazioni}">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="account" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="false" name="account"><c:out value = "${rip.getAccount().getNickname()}"/></td>
                        <td id="corso" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="false" name="corso"><c:out value = "${rip.getRipetizione().getCorso().getNome_Corso()}"/></td>
                        <td id="professore" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="false" name="professore"><c:out value = "${rip.getRipetizione().getProfessore().getCognome()}"/></td>
                        <td id="giorno" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="false" name="giorno"><c:out value = "${rip.getGiorno()}"/></td>
                        <td id="ora" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="false" name="ora"><c:out value = "${rip.getOra()}"/></td>
                        <td id="stato" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="false" name="stato"><c:out value = "${rip.getStato()}"/></td>
                        <td>
                           <span  id="table-remove" class="table-remove"><button type="button" id="button-d" class="btn btn-success" >Prenota</button></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
```

I would like to make a function in which at the time of loading the page analyzes the STATUS column and where it finds "Deleted" I must disable the button and change the color of the text "Canceled" from black to red, while where State has value "Activate" he must do nothing

I tried to do this function

```js
$(document).load('.table-remove',function(){
   var row = $(this).closest('tr');
   var text=row.find('td:eq(4)').text();
   if(text==="Disdetta"){
       $(this).prop("disabled",true);
   }
});
```

but doing so no longer works

Comment: You want `$(document).ready(...)`. `.load` does something completely different. (I guess you're thinking of `$(window).onload(...)` - but `$(document).ready(...)` is almost always better.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a reduced example showing how you can do:

```js
// on load...
$(document).ready(function() {
  // ...for each row...
  $('tbody tr').each(function() {
    var $statusCell = $(this).find('td:first-child');
    // ...get status
    var status = $statusCell.text();
    // if status is "Deleted"...
    if (status === 'Deleted') {
      // ...disable button...
      $(this).find('button').prop('disabled', true);
      // ...and change text color
      $statusCell.css('color', 'red');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Deleted</td>
        <td>
          <button>Do something</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Other status</td>
        <td>
          <button>Do something</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```